# Hide the (obvious) relation from nested serializer in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Django + rest framework. This seems like it should be a frequent and common issue, but I could not find anything like it, so here I ask:

I have a Document and its Items:

```
class DocumentSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    ...
    items = ItemsSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Document
        exclude = ()

class ItemsSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = DocumentItem
        exclude = ('document', )  # hide the ForeignKey as it should be obvious by nesting
```

Expected result for JSON serialized data something like:

```
{ 
  "id": 1, "date": "2021-01-01T00:00:00Z", "title": "Test doc", 
  "items": [
    {"code": 43, quantity: 3}, 
    {"code": 28, quantity: 15}
  ]
}
```

It should be fairly obvious that the "document" field from ItemsSerializer should be derived from the parent serializer at the time of storage. The field itself being a ForeignKey to Document, of course.

However, I can't get past the `ValidationError({"document":["This field is required."]})`.
If I say the field is not required, then `save()`complains `AssertionError: The '.create()' method does not support writable nested fields by default.`

What is the accepted way of handling relations like this in serializers?

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers

Comment: Thank you @iklinac. It seems I gave up on step two exactly where I should have consulted the docs. Unfortunately, the docs did not turn up for me, seems my search-fu is weak :(

Comment: @iklinac: can you please post an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

1. Check if it makes sense to have a Document without Items.
2. Always when you have nested Serializer, method @create and @update should be overridde. [Check documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations)